# How to get a variable with same value on every page of a pagination using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to used a same variable in every pages of my pagination system but the variable is reloading on each page! That's what I want to avoid

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use browsers local storage  like this

```
localStorage['page']=6
```